# App crashes when calling setAdapter(cursorAdapter) method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an app which can display the list of contacts based on specified search String using Fragments.
But the app seems to crash during the layout drawing without doing or showing anything.

The code to the ContactsFragment.java:

```
package com.example.contacts;
import ...

public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
    };
    private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
            android.R.id.text1
    };
    ListView contactsList;
    long contactID;
    String contactKey;
    Uri contactURI;

    public ContactsFragment(){}

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, container, false);
    }
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        contactsList = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                                                R.layout.contact_list_item,
                                                null,
                                                FROM_COLUMNS,
                                                TO_IDS,
                                                0);
        contactsList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);       //THROWS NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
        contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private static final String[] PROJECTION =
            {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
            };
    private static final int CONTACT_ID_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int CONTACT_KEY_INDEX = 1;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?";
    private String searchString="";
    private String[] selectionArgs = { searchString };

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long rowID) {
        Cursor cursor = ((CursorAdapter)(parent.getAdapter())).getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        contactID = cursor.getLong(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
        contactKey = cursor.getString(CONTACT_KEY_INDEX);
        contactURI = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactID, contactKey);
        /*
         * You can use contactUri as the content URI for retrieving
         * the details for a contact.
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        /*
         * Makes search string into pattern and
         * stores it in the selection array
         */
        selectionArgs[0] = "%" + searchString + "%";
        // Starts the query
        return new CursorLoader(
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                SELECTION,
                selectionArgs,
                null
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

The error is in the *onActivityCreated* method in the `contactsList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);` line which throws a `NullPointerException`. I have not created the search widget yet as I'm not able to properly resolve the layout and linking.

Also the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
package com.example.contacts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I'm attaching `activity_main.xml` for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/contact_view"
        android:name="com.example.contacts.ContactsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using two files for the fragments layout - `contact_list.xml` and `contact_list_item.xml` which are respectively:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

The idea is that the fragment will have a `ListView` which will contain the individual items as `TextView`.

I have mentioned that the app uses contact permission in the app's manifest file.

Here are the crash logs:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.contacts, PID: 25682
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contacts/com.example.contacts.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.contacts.ContactsFragment.onActivityCreated(ContactsFragment.java:56)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2619)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6683)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2687)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
I/art: Enter while loop.
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this as I'm quite new to Android Programming.

Comment: kindly share your crash logs

Comment: @ErselanKhan added the crash logs

Comment: The error tells you that `contactsList` is `null`. You need to find out why.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice apparently, I used wrong id in ___findViewById()___ which caused the problem. Now its working. thanks .

Comment: @humble_barnacle Glad you found the problem. It looks like your original post was the correct code and you editted it with the actual error. Feel free to post an answer to explain what the fix was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `NullPointerException` is due to the fact that the code is trying to access (or bind) to an id which has not been used.

The ***id*** given in `findViewById` which should be `R.id.contact_list_view` *instead* of `R.id.contact_list`